# Minimum or ideal amount of information gathered in a purchase form

Tags: website-design, forms, purchase

On a web store I have a purchase form that only asks for email, credit card #, expiration date & CCV (security). This is the minimum requirement to make a transaction.

However, my instinct is that asking for such little amount of information deters users because it seems less secure or less legitimate in some way.

Furthermore, it seems that checkout is an opportunity to find out more information about the user (like name and address).

**Is there a sweet spot of information to ask at checkout that makes the transaction seem secure but is not asking so much that it deters users?**

This is my first question on this forum. Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the things you can do to increase the credibility of your website and reassure users on the security of your checkout process.

**1. Use SSL on your domain name**

[image]

**2. Display SSL Secured logos on your Checkout page**

[image]

**3. Put any other certs that your site is accredited with on the footer of your website or checkout page**

[image]

**4. Display your 24/7 support lines if you have on the checkout page**

[image]

**5. Others, not on checkout page.**

- Put up about us page that describes your company
- Put up physical address of your company location on contact us page
- List down contact numbers and support emails on the contact us page
- Put up pictures of the people behind the website on the "about team" page

**Summary**

All these will send a message to the user - "*We are a serious company with a physical address where you can walk-in if necessary, real people behind the website who are ready to help, who are accessible 24/7 with these phone numbers and emails, who take the business seriously. Therefore, we have taken all the measures to make your purchase on our website pleasant and **secure***".

Note: Btw, do not add more text fields on the checkout page if they are not required. You can collect more info from users at other times, **but not during checkout process**.

Answer (score 1):

> However, my instinct is that asking for such little amount of information deters users because it seems less secure or less legitimate in some way.

My experience has universally been the opposite. That the more information you ask, the fewer transactions you get.

At the point I have got my customer to the checkout (if I'm doing my job right) they've made their purchasing decision. Every additional field or piece of information that I ask for is one more chance for them to abandon that decision.

If you're really concerned, and you have the throughput to do it, a quick A/B test should give you some confidence.